# JS - Combine Multiple Values in Object Into New Key in Same object

Tags: javascript, object

This should be simple, but I am stumbling on it.

What I have:

```
{
 notSet: 2,
 set: 9,
 blanks: 4,
 other: 8
}
```

Into:

```
{
  newKey: 6, (combine notSet and blanks + remove them)
  set: 9,
  other: 8
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this

```js
const obj = {
 notSet: 2,
 set: 9,
 blanks: 4,
 other: 8
}

const transform = ({notSet, blanks, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  newKey: notSet + blanks
})

const newObject = transform(obj)

console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

With delete keyword and a few checks it is possible.
You would want to delete your extra keys.

I used the `??` ([nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) because some keys might not exist, and safer to use a `0` value, otherwise you might get `NaN` (if you try to add `null/undefined` with a `number`):

```js
const obj1 = {
 notSet: 2,
 set: 9,
 blanks: 4,
 other: 8
};

const transformObj = (obj1) => {
obj1.newKey = (obj1.notSet ?? 0) + (obj1.blanks ?? 0);
delete obj1.notSet;
delete obj1.blanks;
};

transformObj(obj1);
console.log(obj1);
```